# Turn Wildfly application on production

Tags: java, mysql, wildfly

I finished my web project, the application server used is Wildfly 30, I made the deploy of the application without any errors now my problem is how I do to turn my application in production on my domain server. If I put in my browser ipaddress:8080/itcmedbr my login page is loaded but if I put only itcmedbr.com that is my domain name, I receive "No possible to access this site." That is my first time that I work to load my project on my domain server in production.
I appreciate any suport.
Thanks and best regards.

after made the deploy by Wildfly console I searched where my file war and this is the result:
find / -name itcmedbr.war
/opt/wildfly-30.0.1.Final/standalone/tmp/itcmedbr.war

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/wildfly-change-default-port for change to port 80/443. Then
update the DNS A record with "domain server"'s public IP.

Comment: Do you have your deployment hosted in the cloud? The port itself would need to be mapped somehow. Either by changing the setting in WildFly or by having some kind of front end HTTP server. If you want to use it without the context you need to name it either ROOT.war or use a jboss-web.xml to define the context.

Comment: Hi James thanks by assistance, yes I've my domain is hosted in a VPS server. I didn't understand when you said about the port I made reference of ipaddrs:8080/itcmedbr only to show that my login page is loaded only by this way, what I want is to inform only itcmedbr.com in the browser to be loaded my web system.

Comment: one more thing, this is the location of itcmedbr.war after the deply of my war file "/opt/wildfly-30.0.1.Final/standalone/tmp/itcmedbr.war".

Comment: `I didn't understand when you said about the port`, by default, Wildfly runs on port 8080, public HTTP servers works on port 80 (or 443), because these are the default ports of the protocol, so you do not need to type http://itcmedbr.com:80/. Anyway, all your questions sounds that this all too broad to explain here. Try to read about "how to run a web server and make it available on the Internet"

Comment: When I call itcmedbr.com on the browser I receive that is not possible to access this site.

Comment: I assume this is a cross-post with https://groups.google.com/g/wildfly/c/9Kfd-7sc6gM/m/zkEw5PfqAQAJ. If so, there are several answers on there.

Answer (score 1):

You do not configure the domain name in WildFly.
You say that when you type

```
http://<ipaddress>:8080/itcmedbr
```

the application loads. Now, The structure of HTTP requests for any application server is following:

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/<appname>
```

Next question is: Do you have a DNS for the name "itcmedbr.com" pointing to the IP address of your host? If yes, then you should be able to access the application by typing

```
https://itcmedbr.com:8080/itcmedbr
```

If that does not work, it means your DNS is not working. Remember, the port number 8080 and the "/itcmedbr" part after the port number are mandatory.

If you want to access your application **only by typing "https://itcmedbr.com"**, then you need to either:

- Setup a web server / proxy in front of WildFly that will redirect the normal web requests (ports 80 for http or 443 for https) to port 8080 **and** the application context "/itcmedbr", or
- Change the default WildFly port to 80 instead of 8080 - but in this case you will still have to type the "/itcmedbr" after the hostname, i. e. the address will be **https://itcmedbr.com/itcmedbr**

The first option is the best as you can control great many things with the proxy, but it is also more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

all that the group said me to made I made and nothing solved my problem, I setup my ip address on /etc/hosts, I alter domain.xml and host.xml and problem still the same, are there a doc to configure a domain name into wildfly 30? I read Wildfly Getting Startted Guide and Administration Guide but I can't see where I configure my domain name.

Hi Nikola, yes I have a domain itcmedbr.com hosted in an VPS server, below configuration of standalone.xml and jboss-web:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:80}"/>

        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="${jboss.mail.server.host:localhost}" port="${jboss.mail.server.port:25}"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
<jboss-web>

    <context-root></context-root>

    <virtual-host>itcmedbr.com</virtual-host>

</jboss-web>
```

My problem now is that i am receiving a error when deploy my application after made some changes the error is "No failure-description provided".

Hi, I solved the problem of deploy, but my webapp is not opened in the browser, this contact are closed I'll open another contact, thanks for all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).